# Google Cloud SDK Python3 mail - how to test in local environment?

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

This is about Google Cloud, Google App Env standard, for python, version 3.X, mail bundled services.

According to [this document from GCP](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/services/mail), bundled mail is re-enabled in GAE for python3, which is very good news.

According to the doc, and the [git samples it references](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-python-standard), you are supposed to import mail from google.appengine.api, but on a local development machine that doesn't work: Importing google collides with the standard google library in the framework.

Here's what happens:

```
~: echo $PYTHONPATH
/Users/lehavi/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine
~: python
Python 3.10.10 (v3.10.10:aad5f6a891, Feb  7 2023, 08:47:40) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import google
>>> google.__path__
_NamespacePath(['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google'])
>>>
```

The google module is taken from a different place, not the appengine, even though I forced my PYTHONPATH to the latter (google.appengine.api.mail is located in that path.)

Any idea how to work around this and test my code locally before deploying to the cloud?

Thank you!

Comment: isn't better if you test your code locally from a virtual env ?

Answer (score 2):

1. When using Python 3, you should create a virtual env
2. You also have to add `appengine-python-standard>=1.0.0` to your `requirements.txt` file and `app_engine_apis: true` to your `app.yaml` file
3. When you run your app with `dev_appserver.py app.yaml`, it will install  the bundled APIs in your virtual env and so all imports such as `from google.appengine.api import mail` will **come from the virtual env** and not the standard google library in the framework or your google cloud sdk directory.

When you're on dev environment, you'll get the following message when you send a mail -

....*You are not currently sending out real email.  If you have sendmail installed you can use it by using the server with --enable_sendmail*...

Comment: Since `dev_appserver.py` requires Python 2, might it be a better long-term option to just mock `google.appengine.api.mail`?  I suspect that Google is not going to maintain `dev_appserver.py`...

Comment: @newname - Google initially didn't support running Python 3 Apps with ```dev_appserver.py``` . Due to complaints 'cos of gaps btw GAE prod & the idiomatic way of running Python Apps, Google had to provide support. These gaps still exist & IMHO Google will continue supporting ```dev_appserver.py``` so far as these gaps exist. E.g. GAE Prod uses the routes in ```app.yaml``` file to handle static files, GAE Prod allows for micro-service architecture & handles routing using ```dispatch.yaml```. Without ```dev_appserver.py```, you can't test (or easily) those capabilities on your dev machine.

Comment: @newname - In addition, the bundled APIs in Python 3 don't work without ```dev_appserver.py``` (need to check if things have changed in later releases of gcloud SDK/CLI). So, if this condition continues to be true, then ```dev_appserver.py``` will need to be supported.

Comment: Thanks NCL, it does say so in the docs, apologies for missing that.
Having reinstalled python2 (...) and overcame dev_appserver.py not finding environment variables (?), it now fails being unable to bind localhost:8080 in wsgi_server.py (line 445). Any ideas?

Comment: Did you remember to wrap your app object i.e. do you have this in your code - ```app.wsgi_app = google.appengine.api.wrap_wsgi_app(app.wsgi_app)```

Comment: I'm in Flask... is there an equivalent? Thank you!

Comment: That code is for Flask. Search for 'Example for a Flask App' on [the documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-python-standard)

Comment: Works! Thank you so much NCL. (This whole thing looks a bit, um, unintended, and so "Hi ho hi ho to SendGrid we go")